# Is there a way to open Google Chrome in incognito-mode by default?

Tags: google-chrome

I was wondering if there is a way to open Google Chrome in incognito-mode by default? Sometimes I work with important web-applications in Chrome, and it is becoming quite a mission to do the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> combo everytime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not by default, but you can add a parameter to make it open in Incognito.

> - Place a Google Chrome shortcut on the desktop (or any other desired location).    [image]
> - Rename the shortcut to any convenient name like “ Private Chrome”.
> - Right click on the shortcut and select “Properties”.     [image]
> - On the “Target” field add an –incognito to the end of program path. (Note: Make sure there is a space between the last apostrophe and the
>     dash)   [image]
> - Your incognito browser is now ready for launch. If you select “New Window” from settings, you will get a normal non-incognito chrome
>     window.

Comment: Thats a tricky move:)

Comment: Can you summarize that link, so that if the link goes dead, your answer is still useful? Otherwise this answer is prone to link rot.

Comment: there you go buddy Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Not at the moment.

And you should be aware that newly created bookmarks as well as downloaded files are always saved, even in Incognito Mode.